# How to create dynamic matrix of structs c?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, matrix

i'm having a little trouble with making a dynamic matrix of structs. With dynamic matrix, what i mean is not a fixed number of columns or lines. I have a fixed number of columns(26 the letters of the alphabet) but i want the number of lines to change in every column.

So this is what i've done so far...

```
struct cliente {
   char nome[9];
   struct cliente* next;
};

typedef struct cliente *ClienteSing;
typedef ClienteSing* Cliente[26];

//I'm allocating memory for the matrix. r is an array that tells me the number of lines for a column.
void initArrayCliente (Cliente a, int* r){
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<26;i++)
      a[i]=(ClienteSing) calloc (r[i],sizeof(struct cliente));
}

//I'm implementing a hash, so in case of collision, i make a linked list from a position in the matrix. This function puts a client i want to insert, in the correct position in case of collision.
void ultimoRamo (ClienteSing a, ClienteSing b){
   ClienteSing temp;
   temp=a;
   while (temp->next!=NULL)
      temp=temp->next;
   temp->next=b;
}

//I create a client b from a str that contains the client name. In case that the position in the matrix is set to null(doesn't have cliente) i insert b there. Otherwise, i will use the previous function to create a linked list from that position. indice is the position i want to insert in to. It's a value generated by my hash 
void insere(Cliente a, char* str, int indice){

   ClienteSing b;
   b= (ClienteSing) malloc (sizeof(struct cliente));
   strcpy (b->nome, str);
   b->next=NULL;

   if (a[str[0]-'A'][indice]==NULL)
   {
      a[str[0]-'A'][indice]=b;
      printf("Livre\n");
   }
   else {
      ultimoRamo(a[str[0]-'A'][indice],b);  
      printf("Colisão\n");
   }
}
```

I can compile this with no problems, it insert well and doesn't give me any segmentation fault... but when i print what i have in the matrix, it gives me garbage... If i print that same cell inside the insert function, it can print with no problems... Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Some risky business: you don't check if str[0] is indeed an uppercase letter.  Neither do you check that `strlen(str) < sizeof b->nome`.  Post the code for the printing function, the problem may hide there.

Comment: @chqrlie My str is allways of size 6. It's in format AA111 for example. I check this outside this code :) Here is the code i use for printing http://paste2.org/DZfE6LhO   As i said, i don't have any segmentation fault, even in the printing. It just prints garbage.

Comment: you assume `str` is always `6` and starts with an uppercase letter, but make your code resilient to erroneous input that may sooner or later occur.  The next programmer will not know what assumptions you made.  You may even be the next programmer...

Comment: I am 100% shure friend :) I read and validate the words. I transform the letters to uppercase and only if they are of that format i let them pass to this functions. They get knocked off the program if they don't obey this rules :)

Comment: Then write an explicit comment before this function to explain why you do not check the arguments for sanity. This way the reader (and potential maintainer) will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your printing code is erroneous:

```
for(z=0;z<26;z++)
    for(t=0;t<arrayCliente[z];t++)
        if(a[z][t].nome==NULL){printf("Fodeu-se");}
        else printf("%s",a[z][t].nome);
```

`a[z][t].nome` is an array of `char`, not a pointer to `char`.  As such, it is only `NULL` if `a[z][t]` is itself `NULL`, and only by chance because `nome` is the first member of this structure.

Furthermore, you allocate and manipulate arrays of structures, not arrays of pointers to structures.  Comparing `a[str[0]-'A'][indice]==NULL` is meaningless.

I suggest you get rid of the pointer and more importantly the array `typedefs`, a very confusing C construct.  Then make the matrix an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to structures.

Comment: So delete the typedefs, and just make a ClientSing. Then making ClientSing **a; Malloc number of columns, and for each c malloc number of lines? Is that it?

Comment: Make `a` an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to `struct ciente` structures.  `struct cliente *a[26];` where `a[i] = calloc(r[i], sizeof(struct cliente*));`

Comment: For a strictly conforming program, you should then initialize each pointer in the pseudo matrix to `NULL` as null pointers are not necessarily all bits zero.  In practice, I have never come across an actual CPU where all bits zero are not `NULL` pointers.  But someone out there may have a spare DS9K emulator to confirm my point.

Comment: I will give it a shot. I'll let you know how it goes.